# Adding dependent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a question concerning the sum of $\underline{dependent}$ random variables $X_i$: 
We define $N$ the random variable that counts how many positive random variables have to be added to surpass $1$, knowing that $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = c$ (and we can also assume $X_i \geq 0$ a.s.), i.e.
$$N = min (k \in \mathbb{N}\mid \sum_{i = 1}^k X_i \geq 1)$$
I would think that $\mathbb{E}[N] \leq 1/c$ but is this to be expected?
What is the expected N?
Thank you!

EDIT: We assume $X_i \leq 1$

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb E[N] \le 1/c$?  You already assumed what $\mathbb E[X_i]$ was.

Comment: It's not enough to just know $E[X_i]$.  If, say, each $X_i$ were identically $2$ then $N=1$.  But if $X_i$ is $0$ with probability $.99$ and $X_i=200$ with probability $.01$ then we still have $E[X_i]=2$ but now $E[N]$ is a lot bigger than $1$ (indeed $E[N]=100$).

Answer (score 1):

$N$ might not even exist, or if it does exist it might be enormous.  Consider the case where with probability $1/2$ all $X_i = 0$ and with probability $1/2$ all $X_i=1$.
Thus $\mathbb E[X_i] = 1/2$.  When all $X_i = 0$, $N$ does not exist, while when all $X_i = 1$, $N = 1$.

Or if you want to assume $X_i > 0$ a.s., let $U$ be uniform on $[0,1]$ and all $X_i = U$.
Then $N = \lceil 1/U \rceil$, and $\mathbb E[N] = \infty$.

Comment: You are right, I meant $\mathbb{E}[N] \leq 1/c$, but what I forgot to mention is that the $X_i \leq 1 a.s.$. I just realized that you counter example still covers this. Thank you!